# How can use Bootstrap clearfix for clearing floats?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I have a WordPress theme in my `single.php` page. Below follows the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="single-post">
                single post content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div id="sidebar-area">
                sidebar area
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#single-post,
#sidebar-area {
    margin:10px auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Image Presentation

[image]

When my single post content height is shorter than the side bar area, some of sidebar widgets goes to under the single content area.
How can I show all sidebar widgets within sidebar area if the sidebar taller than single content by using Bootstrap `clearfix` class?

Comment: Use bootstrap grid to make 8 (any content on left) and 4 (your sidebar) collums divs and everything that you put into 4 col div will be here and doesn't matter how long will be your sidebar. Maybe I just didn't understand you question - sorry then - but why u wanna use clearfix?

Comment: simple example that should help you - if i understood you http://www.bootply.com/teLpSeImf6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reply me but my problem it is solved
i used this grid below within my sidebar widget because it is repeated with every widget and i removed the code and pasted within `sidebar.php` file and my problem solved and all widgets shown in sidebar area

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
</div>
```